# Javascript how to remove decimals after the comma

Tags: javascript, decimal, decimalformat

```
    function deductibleAmount(FileSize) {
    return FileSize / 1000000 + " MB";

}
```

So this is the function I have to turn my FileSize in bytes to MB but the outcome looks something like this: 27.254161 MB but I want 27.25 MB therefor the four last decimals will have to be removed. How can i do this?

Comment: `1000000` that's not a megabyte.

Comment: `var num = 27254161/1000000;
var n = num.toFixed(2);`   for more information [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

Comment: @berkaykılıç It didn't work.